# Native Interface for J2Me device Codename One

Tags: java-me, native, codenameone

I created an Interface class:

```
  package userclasses;
  import com.codename1.system.NativeInterface;

   public interface NativeJ2MEInterface extends NativeInterface {

       public void pollBackground();
   }
```

This is the native class - after I edited it:

```
  package userclasses;
  import userclasses.StateMachine;

  public class NativeJ2MEInterfaceImpl {

      public void pollBackground() {

         try {
            Date now = new Date();
            long timeToRun = now.getTime() + (1000 * 60 );

            System.out.println("RUNNNNNNN forest runnn!");

            PushRegistry.registerAlarm(StateMachine.class.getName(), timeToRun);
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println("EXC-1:"+e.getMessage());
          }

      }

      public boolean isSupported() {
          return true;
      }

  }
```

I want to call the javax.microedition.io.PushRegistry registerAlarm method, but my Codename One J2ME build fails saying:

```
  error: cannot find symbol
  PushRegistry.registerAlarm(StateMachine.class.getName(), timeToRun);
```

I added a midp_2.1.jar to the native j2me directory, but it did not work.
How can I get this to work? Or how can I directly access j2me alarm API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add the jar, it will get packaged into the final build.

Try setting the build argument `j2me.ashaNative=true`.